# Magento 2 Commerce Customer Segmentation Non Login User

Tags: customer-segmentation, dynamic-blocks

I am working with Magento 2 commerce (2.4). We need to show different content for users coming from different locations (We have different content for each state). And I am planning to use Magento 2 Customer Segmentation and Dynamic blocks for it. Few questions that I have are,

1. Is it possible to tag a visitor (Non logged user) as a customer, If so how can I do it?
2. Is it possible to use a dynamic block with customer segment filter to show different content with respect to the user location. If so how can I do it?
3. Is using customer segments the best possible solution for showing content with respect to the user location? Do it have any impact on site performance.